# Markov Chain Modeling

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

A diagnostic test is applied to determine the status of a component which is known to be in one of two states (state 1 and state 2). Let a denote the probability that the test indicates that the component is in state 1. The diagnostic test is applied repeatedly until a stopping condition is satisfied. Let $Y_{1}(t)$ denote the number of the first  applications of the test that indicate that the component is in state 1, and let $Y_{2}(t)$ denote the number of the first  applications of the test that indicate that the component is in state 2,t=1,2,... .  The applications of the diagnostic test terminate when
$Y_{1}(t)-Y_{2}(t)=q$

where q is some positive integer. Model the application of the diagnostic test using a discrete-time Markov chain.

Can someone explain to me how to model this problem as Markov chain.

Thanks

Comment: This is a one-dimensional random walk with an absorbing boundary at $q$. Try searching for that to get some examples of how to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks .. It's as you mentioned a random-walk problem